# Как правильно выполнить sql файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть sql oracle скрипты в файлах, со всякими символами(";") и конструкциями, которые не нравятся `cx_Oracle`:

```
exec :V_VER := '';
...
set serveroutput on
declare
...
begin
...
exception when no_data_found then
...
end;
/
...
```

Я пытаюсь их выполнить так:

```
connect = cx_Oracle.connect()
cur = connect.cursor()
cur.execute(open(Файл.sql).read())
```

однако возникает ошибка.

Но если запихнуть текст скрипта через `subprocess.Popen` в `sqlplus` , то файл выполняеться(но наверное это плохой способ?):

```
db = subprocess.Popen(['sqlplus', '-S', '...'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
db.stdin.write(open(Файл.sql).read())
db.stdin.close()
db.communicate()
```

Как правильно и просто выполнять такие файлы с использованием `cx_Oracle` или др библиотек.?

Comment: имею виду выполнить

Answer (score 0):

это у вас псевдокод ведь? в части open() не очень нравится - во-первых параметр имени файла в кавычках, во-вторых надо проследить, что вы файл как строку читаете. Текст ошибки тоже был бы полезен.